# What really is \0A\00 in llvm string

Tags: llvm

I'm just a beginner on llvm assembly and I like to ask question about
everything I'm uncertain about.

I was just looking at the hello world program
and @str = internal constant [13 x i8] c"hello world\0A\00"

I don't understand what the suffix means
\0A\00 I tried getting read of it and it ended up not having a newline at the output
however if I just have \0A the newline comes back... I feel like \00 is useless...
is it true?

Comment: It's only useless if you don't mind having all of the rest of your computer's memory in your string after the hello world part. NULL is the string terminator.

Answer (score 6):

In LLVM IR syntax, a backslash followed by two hex characters means a character whose [ASCII value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is the same as that defined by the two characters.

In this case, the characters are those at index 10 (0xA) - which is a newline - and at index 0, which is called "null" and is used to terminate strings in many different systems. In C-line languages, those would be written as `\n` and `\0`  (or just 0) instead, with `\0` being implicitly added to the end of literal strings in C (but not in LLVM IR).

In other words, the string you see is equivalent to `"hello world\n"` in C.

Note: although it *is* possible to work with non-null-terminated strings, it's very unhealthy and a lot of built-in string operations will have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on those. Don't omit the null termination.